# How class-based views determine which template file will be called?

Tags: python, django

here's the code:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path("books/", views.BookListView.as_view(), name="books"),
]
```

and the views

```
# views.py

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
```

**Book** is a class in **models.py**, this view will using **book_list.html** template. My question is:

Why does it knows what templates will be called? I didnt even give the **template_name** to it. just like this

```
template_name = 'book_list.html'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will look for the `book_list.html` because the default `template_name_suffix` property for that class is defined as `_list`, which means that if you do not define a `template_name` or `template_name_suffix` yourself, Django will look for the `book_list.html` template.

The `book` part comes from the fact that your model is called `Book`, it is then concatenated with `template_name_suffix`, in this case with `_list` and finally, `.html` is appended as file extension.

You can take a look at the actual code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L161). (`ListView` inherits from `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`.)

Answer (score 0):

In **ListView** when you don't specify `template_name` explicitly, it takes lowercased models name and adds _list to the end. Like your model is Book and it will search for `book_list.html`

If you want your own suffix to be applied instead of `_list` you need to specify it like this:

`template_name_suffix = '_myown`'

In addition, [this website](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) is very helpful to see all methods and usage of Class-based views.

Answer (score 0):

Generic Listview will look for the model name and suffix with '_list'. Have a look the below class that does this in Django

```
class MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):
    """
    Mixin for responding with a template and list of objects.
    """
    template_name_suffix = '_list'

    def get_template_names(self):
        """
        Return a list of template names to be used for the request. Must return
        a list. May not be called if render_to_response is overridden.
        """
        try:
            names = super(MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, self).get_template_names()
        except ImproperlyConfigured:
            # If template_name isn't specified, it's not a problem --
            # we just start with an empty list.
            names = []

        # If the list is a queryset, we'll invent a template name based on the
        # app and model name. This name gets put at the end of the template
        # name list so that user-supplied names override the automatically-
        # generated ones.
        if hasattr(self.object_list, 'model'):
            opts = self.object_list.model._meta
            names.append("%s/%s%s.html" % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name, self.template_name_suffix))

        return names
```